# Python re: getting quotes or double quotes

Tags: python-3.x

I trying to creat a little programming language just for fun.

I want to make:
`string_char = 'hello world' or "hello world"`

I trying this:
`search_str = "([A-z].*) = '(.*)'|/"(.*)/""`

But return none

PS:There is a module to create the grammar (rules) and the syntax of a language?

Comment: Can you post your code? If the above 2 lines is all you did, then obviously you will need to write more as Python doesn't have its Regex capabilities built in- you will need to import them from either the re or regex modules.

Comment: Also I'm almost positive the second string is invalid as you don't escape it midway through.

Comment: Did you mean `"\(.*)\"` im the second part of your regular expression? You need to use the backslash (`\`) to escape characters. The forward-slash (`/`) doesn't escape the next character.

Answer (score 0):

in a txt file it has:
a = "hello world"

but it can be written in two ways:
a = 'hello world'

I want a regex that looks for both ways of writing I offer this code but it returns none.

```
    import re

syntaxe_strvar = "([A-z].*) = '(.*)' | \"(.*)\""

data1 = 'a = "hello world"'
data2 = "b = 'hello world'"

sstr = search(syntaxe_strvar,data1)
print(sstr)
sstr = search(syntaxe_strvar,data2)
print(sstr)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question or did you mean to add this as detail for your question? If it's the former, please flesh out your answer. While code-only answers may answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by adding some explanation. See [answer]. If it's the latter, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28904080) this into your question instead of clicking "add an answer". Answers must provide a complete answer to the question.